# Password generator with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Iam going to write a program in which it generates a random password when I press the Generate button and shows it in a box. and below it a stopwatch starts to countdown.I have written it and I dont have problem in generating password. my only problem is my stopwatch works only once and after that whenever I press generate I only get random password and  stopwatch does not work anymore.
here is my code:

```
import random,time
from tkinter import *

win=Tk()
win.title('Password generator')

def PasswordMaker():
   e1.delete(0,'end')
   small_letters = list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)))
   big_letters = list(map(chr, range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1)))
   digits = ""
   i = random.randint(0, 25)
   j = random.randint(0, 25)
   k = random.randint(0, 1)
   for _ in range(0, 6):
       digits += str(random.randint(0, 9))
   lst = list(big_letters[j] + small_letters[i] + digits)
   random.shuffle(lst)
   password="".join( lst[h] for h in range(8))
   password=str(password)
   e1.insert(END,password)


t = 3
def countdown():
   global t
   if t > 0:
       print(t)
       l1.config(text=t)
       t = t - 1
       l1.after(1000, countdown)
   elif t == 0:
       print('end')



lb=Label(win,text="Password Generator",font=('arial 20')).pack()
e1=Entry(win,font=('arial 13'))
e1.pack()
lb2=Label(win,text="Remaining Time :",font=('arial 10')).pack()
bt=Button(win,text="Generate",font=('arial 15'),fg='red',command=lambda : 
[PasswordMaker(),countdown()])
bt.pack()

l1 = Label(win, font='arial 20')
l1.pack()


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Isn't it because you only set `t = 3` once, when the script is initialized?

Comment: I set t=3  just for testing the code. I should have put it in my PasswordMaker function body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to reset back the `t` to 3 everytime you hit that `Generate` button.

Just change `PasswordMaker` to :

```
def PasswordMaker():
    global t   # ----------------------> Here
    e1.delete(0, 'end')
    small_letters = list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)))
    big_letters = list(map(chr, range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1)))
    digits = ""
    i = random.randint(0, 25)
    j = random.randint(0, 25)
    k = random.randint(0, 1)
    for _ in range(0, 6):
        digits += str(random.randint(0, 9))
    lst = list(big_letters[j] + small_letters[i] + digits)
    random.shuffle(lst)
    password = "".join(lst[h] for h in range(8))
    password = str(password)
    e1.insert(END, password)
    t = 3  # -----------------------> Here
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro, I was dealing with it for couple of days , I couldnt think how much it was easy to slove,( DAMET GARM DADASH! :D). now could you please help me how can I disable the Generate button while counter is counting down?

Comment: @ali.s Happy to help. Since your question has nothing to do with this one, better to ask e new question. I will cover you then. short answer : change the `'state'` of the `bt` button.